# tikz visualization of matrix vector multiplication

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, tikz-datavisualization

I would like to visualization the multiplication between a matrix and vector with color cells as follows, how can I do it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a visualization using `tikz`:

[image]

You can play around with the values to get bigger or smaller vactors, etc. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\filldraw[color=gray!60] (0,0) rectangle (0.6,2); % y vector box
\draw[color=black] (0.9,1.05) -- (1.2,1.05); % equal sign
\draw[color=black] (0.9,0.95) -- (1.2,0.95); % equal sign second line
\filldraw[color=gray!60] (1.4,-0.5) rectangle (3.4,2.5); % matrix box
\filldraw[color=gray!60] (3.8,0) rectangle (4.4,2); % x vector box


\begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=.6] % blue lines
\filldraw[color=blue!40] (3.8,0) rectangle (4.4,2); 
\filldraw[color=blue!40] (1.4,2.5) rectangle (3.4,1.9);
\filldraw[color=blue!40] (1.4,1.3) rectangle (3.4,0.7);
\end{scope}

% letters y, x and A:
\node at (0.3,1){y};
\node at (4.1,1){x};
\node at (2.4,1){A};

% curly braces to illustrate vector and matrix size:
\draw[decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate]
  (4.5,0) -- node[right=6pt] {$n$} (4.5,2); % x vector size (vertical)
\draw[decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate]
  (1.4,-0.6) -- node[below=6pt] {$n$} (3.4,-0.6); % A matrix size (horizontal)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I illustrated the multiplication between a matrix and a vector as requested and not the sparsity as shown in the picture. To change this, simply change the blue lines.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the code is indeed elegant!